# How to print multiple lines from text files in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, io

I have a text file that contains three lines of code.
That is,

Hello.
How may I help you?
What can I do for you today?

I tried printing the first line and it worked.Now I want to print the rest of the lines in the console but it's only displaying first line 4 times like this.

Hello.
Hello.
Hello.
Hello.

Below is the code that I am trying to run and the file is in root folder.

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        /*open the file */
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String greeting = null;
        int rand;
        File file = new File("Greetings.txt");

        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            /*read the file*/
            String greetingPicker = null;

            /*single greeting*/
            /*greeting = greetingPicker;*/
            List<String> listOfGreetings = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((greetingPicker = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                listOfGreetings.add(greetingPicker);
            }
            reader.close();

            rand = (int) Math.random() * (listOfGreetings.size()) + 1;
            greeting = listOfGreetings.get(rand - 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfGreetings.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println(listOfGreetings.get(counter));
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("File cannot be found!!");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the value for the wrong index: You mistakenly used `counter` instead of `i` in your loop. Change this

```
for(int i=0; i < listOfGreetings.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(listOfGreetings.get(counter));
}
```

to this:

```
for(int i=0; i < listOfGreetings.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(listOfGreetings.get(i));
}
```

---

By the way, you are using `Math.random()` and it is instantly converted to a `int`, because you forgot to add correct parentheses, so change this

```
rand = (int) Math.random() * (listOfGreetings.size()) + 1;
```

to this:

```
rand = (int) (Math.random() * (listOfGreetings.size()) + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need your counter, use i ! ;)

```
for(int i=0; i < listOfGreetings.size();i++){
     System.out.println(listOfGreetings.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change

`System.out.println(listOfGreetings.get(counter));`

by

`System.out.println(listOfGreetings.get(i));`

You forgot to change the counter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use counter, and put close in the end like this:

```
    for(int i=0; i < listOfGreetings.size();i++){

        System.out.println(listOfGreetings.get(i));

    }
    reader.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The "counter" variable here is not being incremented:

```
for(int i=0; i < listOfGreetings.size();i++){

     System.out.println(listOfGreetings.get(counter));

}
```

You should change it to "i" instead:

```
for(int i=0; i < listOfGreetings.size();i++){

     System.out.println(listOfGreetings.get(i));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the chunk below. It's simpler and works perfectly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class FileReader{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      //define file path
      String stringFileToRead = "Greetings.txt";

      //the file
      File stringFile = new File(stringFileToRead);

      //Scanner object to take input from  the file
      Scanner fileToRead = null;

      try{
         //Read the file
         fileToRead = new Scanner(stringFile);

      }
      //catch exception
      catch (Exception e){
         System.out.println("Unable to open file.");  
         System.exit(0);
      }

      //print the content of the file 
      System.out.println("The file contains the following contents:\n");
      int lineNum = 1;
      while(fileToRead.hasNextLine()){
         String line = fileToRead.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Line "+lineNum+": "+line);
         lineNum++;
      }

   }

}
```